# How to write a shell function to git push to remote server in batch by conditions

Tags: git, bash, zsh

In my git repo, I may have **Many(the number is  various)** remote repos

For example,

I have `origin` and `origin_1` as my remote repos.

[image]

Every time when I want to push this repo to remote reops, I have to run

`git push origin master`

and

`git push origin_1 master`

I wonder know how to write the kind of similar task  in shell function.

So I can type like `git_push_all` then it will run the command `git push origin master` and `git push origin_1 master`, ..., `git push origin_N master` for me.

I only need some initial ideas, I can write ruby or python.

Comment: If you are using python, use subprocess to execute remote -V and readline() the output, then for each line (split the columns if required) exceute git push using subporcess.

Comment: This does not need either Python o Ruby. I'm tempted to remove both tags :)

Comment: @JamesMills I already did remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the names are exactly as you specified:

```
for i in '' _{1..5}
do 
  git push origin$i master
done
```

For arbitrary names:

```
names=( origin origin_2 origin_3 )
for i in $names
do 
  git push $i master
done
```

As a function:

```
git_push_all() {
  names=( "$@" )
  for i in $names
  do 
    git push $i master
  done
}
```

Usage:

```
git_push_all origin origin_1 origin_5
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can get the names of all remote repositories with `git remote show`. So, if you want to push to all of them, you could just do `for repo in $(git remote show); do git push $repo master; done`.